# Make 2 variables equal to a function, var 1 is automatically changing value to var2

Tags: java

Ok so I made a simple program to practise multi-class in java but I'm not beeing able to find the solution for this problem:

I have 2 `int[][]` variables (coordinates), `coords1` and `coords2`, both equaling a function who asks for the coordinates input,

The strange part is after the first input, `coords1` gets it's values, then I input for `coords2`, which also gets it's values, but at the same time `coords1` will automatically get the same values as `coords2` and I don't know why, here's the code:

```
if(simbolo.equals("circulo") || simbolo.equals("Circulo") || simbolo.equals("Circle") || simbolo.equals("circle")){
            circulo.setColour();
            colour1 = circulo.getColour();
            circulo.setColour(); //circulo 2
            colour2 = circulo.getColour();
            coords1 = circulo.getCoords();                                         //IMPORTANT PART
            System.out.println("coords1: " + coords1[0][0] + " " + coords1[0][1]);//IMPORTANT PART
            coords2 = circulo.getCoords();//circulo2                              //IMPORTANT PART
            //System.out.println("coords2: " + coords2[0][0] + " " + coords2[0][1]);
            System.out.println("2-coords1: " + coords1[0][0] + " " + coords1[0][1]);//IMPORTANT PART
            circulo.setRaio();
            r1 = circulo.getRario();
            circulo.setRaio(); //circulo2
            r2 = circulo.getRario();
            area1 = calcCircleArea(r1);
            perimetro1 = calcCirclePerimeter(r2);
            area2 = calcCircleArea(r1);//circulo2
            perimetro2 = calcCirclePerimeter(r2);
            distance = Distance(coords1, coords2);
            System.out.println("A distância entre os centros dos círculos é: " + distance);
            intersection = Intersects(distance, r1, r2);
            System.out.println(intersection);
        }
```

The first `System.out.println("coords1: " + coords1[0][0] + " " + coords1[0][1]);` will get me a different value than `System.out.println("2-coords1: " + coords1[0][0] + " " + coords1[0][1]);`

Here's function `setCoordinates()`:

```
public int[][] center = new int[1][2];

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public int[][] setCoordinates(){
    System.out.println("Introduza a coordenada do centro: x ");
    center[0][0] = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("y: ");
    center[0][1] = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Centro atual: " + Arrays.toString(center[0]));
    return center;
    }
```

the function in class `circulo` `getCoords()` only gets the returned value from this one.

Edit: the `"IMPORTANT PART"` is where I use those variables

There must be something I'm not doing right but where?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have declared the variable *center* outside the *setCoordinates* method, it is not a local variable for that method. That's why whenever you call the method *setCoordinates* the previous value gets overwritten by the new value. You need to declare the variable *center* inside *setCoordinates* method.